# MySQL Errno 1064

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have this `php` script which updates the fields that I want using three variables `$field`, `$value` and `$id`:

```
<?php

include_once("DBconnect.php");

$field = $_POST["field"];
$value = $_POST["value"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

if(mysqli_query($link," UPDATE users SET $field='$value' WHERE id='$id' ")) {
    echo "INFO1";
}
else {
    echo mysqli_errno($link)." ".mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

And I use this AJAX script to send the three variables:

```
$(document).on("change",".UserEdit_group",function(){

    clearTimeout(TimerVar);
    var UserEditedId = $(this).parents(".tmptr").prev("tr").find(".CPidCell").text().trim();
    var UserEditedLog = $(this).parents(".tmptr").find(".UserEditLog");

    alert (UserEditedId);

    UserEditedLog.html("<img src='Resources/Images/Loader02.gif'/>");
    UserEditedLog.css({"overflow":"hidden"});
    UserEditedLog.animate({"max-height" : "1000px"},1000);

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'useredit.php',
            data: { 'field' : 'group', 'value' : $(this).val().trim(), 'id' : UserEditedId },
            success : function(result){
                clearTimeout(TimerVar);
                if(result == "INFO1") {
                    UserEditedLog.html(" <span style='color: #c9e52d;'>'group' field updated successfully!</span> ");
                    TimerVar = setTimeout( function(){clearUserEditLog()} ,4000);
                }
                else if(result == "ERROR1") {
                    UserEditedLog.html(" <span style='color: #e52d58;'>failed attempt to update 'group' field!</span> ");
                    TimerVar = setTimeout( function(){clearUserEditLog()} ,4000);
                }
                else {
                    UserEditedLog.html(result);
                }
            }
        });
});
```

And this is the HTML dinamicaly added with PHP:

```
<!-- Some more dinamicaly added HTML here -->
<select class='SelectLightThemeShort UserEdit_group'>";
    if($row['group'] == "Members") {
        echo "
            <option value='Members' selected='selected'>Members</option>
            <option value='Moderators'>Moderators</option>";
    }
    else if($row['group'] == "Moderators") {
        echo "
            <option value='Members'>Members</option>
            <option value='Moderators' selected='selected'>Moderators</option>";
    }

    echo "
</select>
<!-- Some more dinamicaly added HTML here -->
```

The thing is that I use the same `PHP` script and `AJAX` script (just with other values) to update other fields and it work perfectly. But when I use it to update the "group" field I get this error:
 `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group='Members' WHERE id='39'' at line 1`
I noticed the two single quotes after that 39 but I can't understand why they are there because this error and that quote appears only when I try to update the "group" field.
Errno `1064`
MySQL version `5.6.15`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it appears you are using a reserved word `group` and if its not escaped using backticks you will get this error

```
if(mysqli_query($link," UPDATE users SET `$field`='$value' WHERE id='$id' "))
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll change it. I was thinking that a reserved word is the problem but in the lists that I checked I did not found the group word.

Comment: Yes its reserved and we use it as `select count(*),country from table group by country`

Comment: If I use `groups` instead of `group` will it solve the problem?